# Comparing a value to a set of values

Tags: distributions

I'll start off by saying I know  very little about statistics, and I'm not sure if some of these methods would even make sense, statistically, to the more initiated statistician. But, I have a vector of data, $V$, and a new piece of data, $\beta$, and I want a way of calculating how 'unexpected' this new value is.

I.e. how out of character it is, how much it doesn't follow the trend, how different it is from what would be expected, given the previous values (in their order). My data is not normalised (but could be if that would make it better?) and I know it follows a power-law distribution. Most likely beta or pareto.

Once I find a way I'll also be weighting the data.

I came up with a few methods, so if someone could tell me which is best, or if they don't even make sense, or if something already exists that would be far better I'd appreciate it. A bonus if the value could be in the range $[-1, 1]$, although I don't see how...

## Comparing the distance to the mean

I think I'm correct in saying the variance of some data is the average squared distance to the mean. So, the squared distance of the new value, $\beta$, to the mean, $\mu$, could also be measured. I.e. $(\beta - \mu)^2$. Then I had a few ideas of how to compare it:

### Largest distance

If the largest value is $M$, then perhaps some metric like:
$$
\frac{(\beta - \mu)^2 - \sigma^2}{(M - \mu)^2}
$$

### Simple ratio

$$
\frac{(\beta - \mu)^2 - \sigma^2}{\sigma^2}
$$

## Adding to the set

If the vector $V$ has the new value, $\beta$, appended to it, so that it's a new vector of data $U = V ; \beta$, then the standard deviation (or variation?) could be compared.

Something like:
$$
\frac{\sigma_V^2 - \sigma_U^2}{\sigma_U^2}
$$

I'm sure there's some far better way I just don't know about. If there is please tell me :)

Thanks.

Comment: Is $\beta$ a scalar value? Do you know its dsitribution shape, but not the precise parameters?

Comment: Search our site for "prediction interval."  Apply this procedure by computing a prediction interval for $\beta$ from $V$ and comparing the observed value of $\beta$ to that interval.

Comment: @cdalitz Yes it's a scalar. It will be a whole number, however (unless normalised).

Comment: @whuber I'll give it a search -- thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be reformulated as classical *hypothesis testing*. In hypothesis testing, you search for a criterion that an observation $x$ is unlikely under a "null hypothesis" $H_0$. Typically, $H_0$ is that $x$ follows a certain probability distribution.

Let us assume that your data follows a Pareto distribution with density $f$, i.e.
$$f(x)=k x_{min} x^{-k-1}$$
Then you can estimate the cutoff parameter $x_{min}$ and the power $k$ from your data vector $V$. In hypothesis testing, test data point $\beta$ is considered "unlikely" to stem from the distribution, if $P(x\geq\beta)$ is below some threshold $\alpha$, the "significance level". Obviously, $\alpha$ is the probability for the error to reject $\beta$ although $H_0$ (that $\beta$ stems form the distribution) is true.

For the Pareto distribution, the reject criterion is
$$\alpha > P(x\geq\beta) = \int_\beta^\infty f(x)\,dx=\left(\frac{x_{min}}{\beta}\right)^k$$

If you do not know the distribution, you can use a non-parametric approach by using the empirical cumulative distribution function for hypothesis testing. Example in R:

```
V <- rnorm(50)  # simulate your data vector randomly
V.cdf <- ecdf(V)
alpha <- 0.01   # significance level 1%
beta.threshold <- quantile(V.cdf, 1-alpha)

# visualize threshold
plot(V.cdf)
abline(v=beta.threshold, col="red")
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks :) I looked into hypothesis testing as I learnt it in A-Levels and remember it. However I have a few questions. 

I want a value that expresses how unlikely it was, so could I just abandon the significance level and, as this will be passed to another function later, just use P(x >= beta) ? Since that's in the range [0, 1].

Also, I still don't know the distribution. Once I find that out it should be fine. But this set is constantly changing -- every time I calcualte this I should re-evaluate the potential parameters x_min and k, right?

Comment: @chris I have edited the answer how this can be done with arbitrary (unknown) distributions of your data, provided you want to reject *large* values. The same can be done with *small* values, of course. As you are a new contributor, please allow me a hint: if an answer answers your question, mark it as an accepted answer (and upvote it). This removes your question from the list of unanswerd questions.

Comment: I think this makes sense. So, the ecdf is a 'generic' distribution, and I can use it (programmatically) if I don't know the distribution. Would it be better to do this, or try and more closely fit a distribution? Since I know it's a power-law distribution.

Also, what did you mean by rejecting large values? I don't really want to reject anything, more just use the P(x >= beta) to find out what the likelihood of this value was.

Comment: @chris If you are sure that it's a power law distribution, estimating its parameters is better than using the ECDF. One reason is that the quantile depends on fewer values than the parameter estimators (warning: this is my intuition, but I cannot strictly prove it). And concerning "rejection": it is completely up to you what you do with the information how probable the region $(\beta,\infty)$ is.

Comment: Okay, so I'll try estimate the parameters (each time). If my intuition is correct here's what I'll do:
1) estimate parameters
2) Check P(x <= beta) (the cdf)
3) That value, the cdf, is the 'probabiltiy of it not being in the distribution'. So use that for my next step.

I'm not entirely sure if that's the correct probability to check, or the one you used P(x >= beta).

Comment: No, you can not compute a probability that it is "not in the distribution". You can only compute a probability how likely $\beta$ is under the hypothesis that it "is in the distribution". This is $P(x \geq \beta)$.

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct method, idk if statistics is what I want after all. This is a time series of data, so I'm trying to find if a value fits a trend. I realised, this would only tell me if this value fits a distribution, not necessarily a trend. What I think I more want is some way to check the error between a value and a time series curve fit?

Comment: If this is not a stationary distribution, but a time series, you should look up a book on time series analysis. A popular model for time series is ARIMA. Searhcing for this term on the internet should yield turorials and literature recommendations.

Comment: Most helpful, I'll close this question and mark yours correct (as if it weren't a time distribution it would be).