# Comparing a new value to a time series

Tags: time-series

I have a time series, of market volume data, in fixed-step time gaps. Given a new value I need a way to compare this new value to the previous vector.

In the time series the most recent values, obviously, impact more on what the next value will be than ones before them. So, some method of weighting should be available.

I have experimented with first fitting a least-squares function, then using various ways of comparing the function to a new value. However I have found it is too temperamental. As this is being used for finance, and it is automated, it must be more robust.

I am thinking on the lines of comparing a weighted mean/variance to the new (squared) distance. I would like this calculated value to be in the range $[0,1]$ as well. If possible.

Thanks.

Comment: When you closed your original version of this question you also destroyed the comment, forcing this community to start all over in guiding you.  Don't do that: just edit the original.  More about how to use this site effectively can be found at our [help].

Comment: BTW, both this and its duplicate appear to be versions of [your first question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539226/comparing-a-value-to-a-set-of-values), which has an accepted answer.  What's the matter with it??

Comment: @whuber I elaborated and my previous question was not reopened... It's not the same. The other guy rthought I meant a statistical distribution, not a time series. I accepted his answer and commented that I did so because, if it were what I asked, it would have been correct. I just wasn't clear enough. I went to try and do it myself but wanted some further advice.